# Pop out menu not displaying on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a pop-out menu on my website but it's currently not working as expected.

Here's my Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/chx1y5w6/

Can someone explain why when I click the burger menu button, the menu does not pop out?

```js
(function(window){

'use strict';

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );









/* Toggle Menu */

(function () {
  'use strict';
  var toggleX = document.querySelector('.toggle-x');
  var classActive = 'active';
  var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
  innerDiv.className = 'toggle-icon-line';
  toggleX.appendChild(innerDiv);

  toggleX.addEventListener('click', onClickHandler);

  function onClickHandler (evt) {
    
    (this.classList.contains(classActive) === true ) ? this.classList.remove(classActive):this.classList.add(classActive);

    if($('body').hasClass('show-menu')){
        toggleMenu();
    }

    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
         toggleMenu(); 
     }
 });

 var bodyEl = document.body,
  content = document.querySelector( '.content-wrap' ),
  openbtn = document.getElementsByClassName( 'toggle-x' ),
  closebtn = document.getElementsByClassName( 'toggle-x' ),
  isOpen = false;

 function init() {
  initEvents();
 }

 function initEvents() {
  openbtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );
  if( closebtn ) {
   closebtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );
  }

  // close the menu element if the target itÂ´s not the menu element or one of its descendants..
  content.addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) {
   var target = ev.target;
   if( isOpen && target !== openbtn ) {
    toggleMenu();
   }
  } );
 }

 function toggleMenu() {
  if( isOpen ) {
   classie.remove( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
  }
  else {
   classie.add( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
  }
  isOpen = !isOpen;
 }

 init();

  }

})();
```

```css
/*! normalize.css v3.0.2 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,menu,nav,section,summary{display:block}audio,canvas,progress,video{display:inline-block;vertical-align:baseline}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden],template{display:none}a{background-color:transparent}a:active,a:hover{outline:0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight:bold}dfn{font-style:italic}h1{font-size:2em;margin:0.67em 0}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sup{top:-0.5em}sub{bottom:-0.25em}img{border:0}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}figure{margin:1em 40px}hr{box-sizing:content-box;height:0}pre{overflow:auto}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{color:inherit;font:inherit;margin:0}button{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer}button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default}button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}input{line-height:normal}input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;box-sizing:content-box}input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:0.35em 0.625em 0.75em}legend{border:0;padding:0}textarea{overflow:auto}optgroup{font-weight:bold}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}td,th{padding:0}html{box-sizing:border-box}*,*:before,*:after{box-sizing:inherit}.wrapper{text-align:center;background:rgba(0,0,0,0);padding:0 0;margin:0 0 0 0;font-size:0}






.toggle{position:relative;overflow:hidden;display:inline-block;margin:0;padding:0;width:48px;height:48px;border-radius:50%;cursor:pointer;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);transition:nd 0.3s}.toggle:focus{outline:none}.toggle .toggle-icon-line{position:absolute;top:23px;left:12px;right:12px;height:2px;background:white}.toggle .toggle-icon-line::before,.toggle .toggle-icon-line::after{content:'';position:absolute;display:block;height:2px;background-color:white;left:0;width:100%}.toggle .toggle-icon-line::before{top:-9px}.toggle .toggle-icon-line::after{bottom:-9px}.toggle-x{background-color:#00b4ff}.toggle-x:hover{background-color:#007eb2}.toggle-x .toggle-icon-line{transition:background 0s linear 0.3s}.toggle-x .toggle-icon-line::before{transition-property:top,-webkit-transform;transition-property:top,transform}.toggle-x .toggle-icon-line::after{transition-property:bottom,-webkit-transform;transition-property:bottom,transform}.toggle-x .toggle-icon-line::before,.toggle-x .toggle-icon-line::after{transition-duration:0.3s,0.3s;transition-delay:0.3s,0s}.toggle-x.active{background-color:#007eb2}.toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line{background:none}.toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line::before{top:0;-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(45deg);transform:rotate(45deg)}.toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line::after{bottom:0;-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);transform:rotate(-45deg)}.toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line::before,.toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line::after{transition-delay:0s,0.3s}

  .toggle {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
   
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
   
    border-radius: 50%;
   
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
   
    transition: background 0.3s;
  }
  .toggle:focus {
    outline: none;
  }

  .toggle .toggle-icon-line {
    position: absolute;
    top: (48 / 2) - (48 / 2);
    left: 12px;
    right: 14px;
    height: 2px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }
   
  .toggle .toggle-icon-line::before,
  .toggle .toggle-icon-line::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
   
  .toggle .toggle-icon-line::before {
    top: -( (48 / 2) - (48 / 2) - 14);
  }
  .toggle .toggle-icon-line::after {
    bottom: -( (48 / 2) - (48 / 2) - 14);
  }

  .toggle-x {
    background-color: rgb(0, 180, 255);
  }
   
  .toggle-x:hover {
    background-color: rgb(0, 126, 178);
  }
   
  .toggle-x .toggle-icon-line {
    transition: background 0s linear 0.3s;
  }
   
  .toggle-x .toggle-icon-line::before {
    transition-property: top, transform;
  }
   
  .toggle-x .toggle-icon-line::after {
    transition-property: bottom, transform;
  }
   
  .toggle-x .toggle-icon-line::before,
  .toggle-x .toggle-icon-line::after {
    transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
  }

  .toggle-x.active {
    background-color: rgb(0, 126, 178);
  }
   
  .toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line {
    background: none;
  }
   
  .toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line::before {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
   
  .toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line::after {
    bottom: 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
   
  .toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line::before,
  .toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line::after {
    transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
  }






.menu-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1001;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2.5em 1.5em 0;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-320px,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(-320px,0,0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
    transition: transform 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

/* Shown menu */
.show-menu .menu-wrap {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
    position:fixed;
}

.show-menu .icon-list,
.show-menu .icon-list a {
}

.show-menu .icon-list a {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.9s;
    transition-duration: 0.9s;
}

.show-menu .content::before {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.8s;
    transition: opacity 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">Hello!</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="toggle toggle-x"></div>

<div class="site-wrap">

  <div id="container">

   <main id="content" role="main" class="scroll">
    <div>
     
  <h1 class="title"><a href="#">Welcome</a></h1>
                    
                </div>
                
            </main>
            
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Open your console -> read this: `Uncaught TypeError: openbtn.addEventListener is not a function`

Comment: first of all `getElementsByClassName ` return an "array"

Comment: @michaelmcgurk first you are calling wrong  openbtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu ); it should like **openbtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu() );**

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara no, please don't tell him mistakes. this code would fire   `toggleMenu`instead of pass it as parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure you have error in

```
openbtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );
```

your `openbtn` is an array

```
document.getElementsByClassName( 'toggle-x' )
```

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns an array and array doesn't have this method. Only array items.

You can just use

```
if (openbtn.length > 0) { openbtn[0].addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu ); }
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Should I give my Toggle button an `ID` and use `getElementByID` instead?

Comment: You can just use `if (openbtn.length > 0) { openbtn[0].addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu ); }`. I edited my post

Comment: Strange. If you click the burger icon twice, it loads the menu :-/

Comment: It is correct. But you have the same problem with `closebtn`. If you use Firefox just press F12 to open Developer Tools and change iframe to something ended with `/show/` for JsFiddle. Then in console tab you can view all errors

Comment: Thanks @suvroc. As you can tell, my JS skills aren't great. Can you help me debug this issue?

Comment: Read more about: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools This is very powerful tool. This is the best help which I can give you in your problem. I use this tool all the time during frontend work.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error (in javascript console throws in initialize!)

> TypeError: openbtn.addEventListener is not a function

You need to control `openbtn` variable and make it a DOM object to manipulate it without problems